# SBT: how to use different versions of the same plugin in a multi-project build?

Tags: sbt

I have a multi-project build and two projects which don't use the same version of the same plugin.

i.e. those two plugins are used by two projects:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.7")
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.13")
```

How can I disable one plugin and enable the other (and vice-versa) for those two projects?

Comment: Hi @Simon , did you manage to find a solution ?